# Testing stellar anchor

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory

I am in process of testing a build of stellar anchor. 
I am using https://gostellar.org/app/ for this.

Everything goes well till the point where the transaction is submitted to the network.

I get this error : 
[image]

I am not sure how to see what is the problem. 
On my side I see no errors.

I am testing the receiving use case using the gostellar app.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to do this. SEP-3 is [deprecated](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0003.md). The current recommended approach for anchors is [SEP-0024](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0024.md), detailed [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/connect-to-wallets.html). This is a cleaned up, simplified approach that is also backwards compatible with the older [SEP-0006](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0006.md).

Comment: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0003.md
Here it says that: for most use cases , we actually recommend the workflow specified in SEP-0006 instead of SEP-0003.
SEP-0003 is enough for us for now . 
Are you saying that SEP-0003 is not supported by the gostellar app ? 
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: It's supported by gostellar. I'm just saying that the ecosystem is moving away from this approach, so you shouldn't build anything new that uses it.